# Loading icon not showing up when submitting a form using IE, but fine with FireFox

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, preloader

I am adding some AJAX and jQuery in a website, and I recently add a loading icon when an AJAX call is made. It works pretty fine, both in IE and Firefox, unless when a form is submitted.
In that case, in works only with FF but not with IE. From what I read, I know it can be related to the fact that the JavaScript is single-threaded and so IE will not display the picture or display it but not animated it. I use to have this kind of behavior but I successfully fixed it. So I' wondering what is wrong this time, but I don't see it, so here is my code.

I bind the loading picture with AJAX events, so it's displayed for each call:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    update_rssfeed();
    $("#preloader").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Then, there is a jQuery call when a click is performed on a submit button of a search form:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#search', function(event){
    // some stuff in javascript

    // ajax call
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "somepage.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            // some stuff here
        }
    });
});
```

The AJAX call is made and the result is correct for both FF and IE, but IE will bot show the loading icon, despite the bind above, while FF will.

I have other ajax calls made in other places that works fine even in IE though.
For instance, this works fine (it's a kind of function called when a click is made on a link, to refresh some part of the page):

```
function foo(args)
{ 
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "somepage.php?" + args,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            // some stuff
        }
    });
}
```

So, my guess is that the problem comes from the way I try to call the function, but I don't see how shoud I do.

EDIT ----------------------------------------------------------------

The solution is to:

- put "async" to "true"
- add event.preventDefault(); to prevent the form to redirect

  ```
  $(document).on('submit', '#search', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // some stuff in javascript

  // ajax call
  $.ajax({
      url: "somepage.php",
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
          // some stuff here
  });
  });
  ```

Comment: you shouldn't use async: false

Comment: Add this line as first line for submit handler and give a try.
event.preventDefault();

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe my problem is in the logic then.
Because if I put "true", the redirection from the form is done right away instead of waiting for the result of the ajax, and so it doesn't work either. I'll give a shot with the event.preventDefault().
Cheers!